# Time complexity of Kronecker product $I_n \otimes Q$ where $Q$ is Toeplitz

Tags: matrices, asymptotics, computational-complexity, kronecker-product, toeplitz-matrices

Given a symmetric Toeplitz matrix $Q$  of size $m$, what is the time complexity of the Kronecker product $I_n \otimes Q$, where $I_n$ is identity matrix of size $n$? Is is $\mathcal{O}(m)$?

Comment: Aren't you just copying $Q$ a total of $n$ times to form a block-diagonal matrix?

Comment: Yes, the resulting matrix is block diagonal